# Building Valkyrie RCP

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build [Valkyrie RCP](https://github.com/cmadsen/Valkyrie-RCP/) from the 1.2 release. According to their instructions, it should be easy: "Just clone the repository, and then use a mvn install command."
However, when I try the command, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project valkyrie-rcp-core: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project dk.navicon:valkyrie-rcp-core:jar:1.2:
>   Failure to find com.l2fprod:l2fprod-common-all:jar:7.3 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I can see that *l2fprod-common-all-7.3.jar* is included in the dependencies folder but Maven seems to be unaware of that. How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's now possible to build it using Gradle, which doesn't have the dependency issues . Also, there's a dependencies folder with batch scripts to install the missing dependencies if you still wish to use Maven.

As of 2.0 Valkyrie RCP will use Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the given version of that dependency does [not exist in Maven Central only older versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.l2fprod).

Answer (score 0):

They would probably suggest you do a `mvn install` first on the file in the dependencies folder, then.

Try go down in deps and do a

```
mvn install -DgroupId=com.l2fprod -DartifactId=l2fprod-common-all -Dversion=7.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=l2fprod-common-all-7.3.jar
```

That would get you past that point locally.

After that re-execute your project build with a `-U`option.

Long term is to find the artifact and include it in a repository that is searchable from your maven settings or project profile.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't quite work, but with some googling I came up with this: mvn -e install:install-file -DartifactId=l2fprod-common-all -DgroupId=com.l2fprod -Dversion=7.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=dependencies\com\l2fprod\l2fprod-common-all\7.3\l2fprod-common-all-7.3.jar
That got me past the first error. But apparently the POM also requires vldocking 3.0.0 while the dependencies folder only contains 2.1.4. But that's a whole new problem.

Comment: perhaps you should consult the developer mailing list to see how they are configured. They might use a special repository or something, because usually dependencies should be resolveable in a transitive manner. While installing a single file or so could be acceptable, installing the entire internet is probably not